# lucas lehmer test.

Tags: number-theory, mersenne-numbers

I asked to use the Lucas_Lehmer test to show that $2^{11} -1$ is prime i was wondering if there are any by hand examples of someone using this test on a mersenne prime that anyone knows of.

I tried googling the test but the explanation in itself confused me so i was hoping to see an example not just a explanation of what the test is. ( i realize this test was intended for computers to be programmed to test primes but i would like to see an example by hand.)

Comment: Do you want me to do the above for a Mersenne prime (e.g. 127) and show you how it works?

Comment: Or a link to any example im sure if i can see how its done once i can figure out how to do it for my example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give an example, let's take $127$. Then, [the algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Lehmer_primality_test#The_test) asks us to do the following:

- Set $s = 4$, step zero.
- $s \to s^2 - 2\mod 127 = 14$, step one.
- $s \to s^2 - 2\mod 127 = 194 \mod 127 = 67$, step two.
- $s \to s^2 - 2\mod 127 = 4487 \mod 127 = 42$, step three.
- $s \to s^2 - 2\mod 127 = 1762 \mod 127 = 111$, step four.
- $s \to s^2 - 2\mod 127 = 12319 \mod 127 = 0$, step five ($= 7 - 2$).

Since $s_5 \equiv 0 \mod 127$, we see that $127$ is a prime number.

Comment: Addendum : Seeing how easy this test is, can tell us why most of the largest primes found thus far are all Mersenne primes, including the largest one found thus far.

Comment: To make it precise: the key is, that for $M_7$ the zero must occur ***at $s_5 = s_{7-2}$ .*** And in general for $M_n$ at $M_{n-2}$.

Answer (score 2):

We define a sequence $s_i$ such that $s_0=4$ and $s_{i+1} = s_i^2 - 2$, and check whether $s_{11-2} \equiv 0 \pmod{2^{11}-1}$.

- $s_0 \equiv 4$
- $s_1 \equiv 4^2 - 2 \equiv 14$
- $s_2 \equiv 14^2 - 2 \equiv 194$
- $s_3 \equiv 194^2 - 2 \equiv 788$
- $s_4 \equiv 788^2 - 2 \equiv 701$
- $s_5 \equiv 701^2 - 2 \equiv 119$
- $s_6 \equiv 119^2 - 2 \equiv 1877$
- $s_7 \equiv 1877^2 - 2 \equiv 240$
- $s_8 \equiv 240^2 - 2 \equiv 282$
- $s_9 \equiv 282^2 - 2 \equiv 1736$

Therefore $2^{11} - 1$ is not prime.

(Note: $2^{11} - 1 = 2047 = 23 \times 89$.)